# Javascript ternary operators for method calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-operator

I would *like* to be able to do this:

```
var b = $(this).is(':checked')
$('.perspective-col'). (b) ? show() : hide()
```

instead of

```
var b = $(this).is(':checked')
if(b) {    
    $('.perspective-col').show() 
} else {
    $('.perspective-col').hide()
}
```

Am I wishing for too much? Or is there some wonderful javascript syntax I haven't found yet? Or am I right in thinking that no such thing exists in JQuery thus far? (I'm using JQuery 1.9.0)

Comment: Another option, different from the current answers, is to use: `$.fn[b ? "show" : "hide"].call($(".perspective-col"))`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this :

```
var b = $(this).is(':checked')
$('.perspective-col')[b ? 'show' : 'hide']()
```

You can call jQuery function by passing a string into the bracket `[]`. Just insert a condition inside to decide which string you pass!

In general,

```
<any expression>.property
```

is equivalent to:

```
<any expression>['property']
```

The difference is that you can replace the literal `'property'` in the brackets with an expression that calculates the property name. jQuery methods are just properties whose values happen to be functions.

But I actually hate that practice. You can also use [jQuery .toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-showOrHide)

Comment: Perhaps note that this works because `<expression>.name` is equivalent to `<expression>['name']`. There's nothing special about method calls or jQuery.

Comment: Feel free to edite my answer if missexplained something (or a better way to say it)! :)

Answer (score 6):

jQuery has a method that does what you want called `toggle()`:

```
$('.perspective-col').toggle(b);
```

Comment: Wow. Time to rewrite half of the javascript I wrote in the past week... xD Thanks!

Comment: With a good IDE, you may be able to rewrite them all using a regexp replace.

Comment: FYI the method I'm writing attempts to show() all columns with class="perspective" based on a checkbox value, regardless of other checkboxes that depend on the individual column, so `toggle()` isn't exactly what I'm looking for right now.

Comment: My answer was based on the code you wrote in the question, where there is a single `b` being used for all elements that match the selector. The same thing applies to Karl-André's answer. If different elements need to be toggled differently, you can use `.each()` and get the appropriate `b`, then use `$(this).toggle(b)`.

Comment: Sorry for not including more information about my intent earlier. Cool, so: `$('some-element').each(function() {var b = $(this).is(':checked'); $(this).toggle(b); } )` Clean.